# Lumia Imaging SDK 3.0 Quick Start error on GrayscaleEffect() on Mobile Emulator 10

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile, lumia-imaging-sdk

I am testing the Lumia Imaging SDK 3.0 [quick start sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt598522.aspx)

The sample works fine on my desktop but produce this error when running on Mobile Emulator 10.

```
 public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();


        double scaleFactor = 1.0;
        scaleFactor = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().RawPixelsPerViewPixel;

        _writeableBitmap = new WriteableBitmap((int)(Window.Current.Bounds.Width * scaleFactor), (int)(Window.Current.Bounds.Height * scaleFactor));
        _thumbnailImageBitmap = new WriteableBitmap((int)OriginalImage.Width, (int)OriginalImage.Height);
        _grayscaleEffect = new GrayscaleEffect();
        _brightnessEffect = new BrightnessEffect(_grayscaleEffect);
        m_renderer = new SwapChainPanelRenderer(_brightnessEffect, SwapChainPanelTarget);

        LoadDefaultImageAsync();
    }
```

The line `_grayscaleEffect = new GrayscaleEffect();` raised the error. `System.IO.FileNotFoundException`

```
at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.GetWinRTFactoryObject(IntPtr pCPCMD)
at Lumia.Imaging.Adjustments.GrayscaleEffect..ctor()
at QuickStart.MainPage..ctor()
at QuickStart.QuickStart_XamlTypeInfo.XamlTypeInfoProvider.Activate_0_MainPage()
at QuickStart.QuickStart_XamlTypeInfo.XamlUserType.ActivateInstance()
```

[image]

I do not have a physical device for Windows 10 mobile to test. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your feedback. I can reproduce your issue while using Mobile Emulator 10.0.10586. But when I tested it on real device, the sample works well. The OS build of the device is also 10586. This issue may related to Mobile Emulator. We have reported this to the SDK team. I will update here once I get further info.

For now, you can test your code with Local Machine or if you have a physical device, you can test on your device.